# Rails console doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.0.0 on my Opensuse but rails console doesn't work.
I have this error message:

```
/home/zellou_i/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
    from /home/zellou_i/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/zellou_i/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/zellou_i/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/zellou_i/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /home/zellou_i/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I don't understand, I installed readline but he can't load it.

Comment: Possible duplicat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340497/cannot-load-such-file-readline-loaderror-when-running-heroku-create-stack

Comment: rvm or rbenv or manually compiled ruby?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby needs to be compiled with readline-support. Make sure you install libreadline6 and its dev headers (debian-specific packages, adapt to suse) and then recompile your ruby.

Comment: I installed libreadline6 I'm sure but I'don't know what are debian-specific package adapt to suse.

Comment: I didn't know if the package is also named libreadline6 on debian. however, you may also need libreadline6-dev (as I said) and then reinstall your ruby _with_ readline support. When manually compiling, you need to provide the path to readline, but I assume your package manager should automatically do this.

Comment: compat-readline4        
  | libguilereadline-v-18-18 
i | libreadline-java        
  | libreadline-java-32bit  
  | libreadline-java-javadoc 
i | libreadline5                
  | libreadline5-32bit          
i | libreadline6                
  | libreadline6-32bit           
  | perl-TermReadLine-Gnu     
  | php5-readline             
i | readline-devel           
  | readline-devel-32bit     
i | readline-doc            
  | readline5-devel          
  | readline5-devel-32bit

Comment: with "i" before the pipe sorry