# Rails console: in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, readline

I've got some errors in my Rails app and I'm trying to start the Rails console by issuing following command:

```
rails console
```

No matter what I try, I'm always getting the same error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/mammie/web/icosole/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
    from /opt/mammie/web/icosole/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/mammie/web/icosole/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:37:in `require'
    from /opt/mammie/web/icosole/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I've really tried every possible solution I found on the net, as many people encounter the same error. Unfortunately, nothing seems to work. When I try the following command:

```
ruby /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.1.1/ext/readline/extconf.rb
```

I get following output

```
checking for tgetnum() in -lncurses... yes
checking for readline/readline.h... yes
checking for readline/history.h... yes
checking for readline() in -lreadline... no
checking for readline() in -ledit... no
checking for editline/readline.h... no
*** /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.1.1/ext/readline/extconf.rb failed ***
```

Indicating that something is missing, but installing readline with apt-get doesn't make a difference either. I'm guessing it could have something to do with incompatible gem versions, as the console worked briefly some time ago. Are there any known version issues with readline? Very much people seem to have encountered problems with this gem.

Comment: I really found the following page helpful: https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Add-Readline-support-to-Ruby-on-Mac-OS-X#using-rvm-and-homebrew  I had issues with readline and irb, as well as rails console. For me, I followed the homebrew section.

Answer (score 14):

Try putting `rb-readline` in your Gemfile and check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/9595841/1905235

Answer (score 7):

If you are running **Rails 4.x** it is possible that [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) is causing this issue.

Try stopping the Spring process `bundle exec spring stop`

Then run `bundle exec rails c`

Answer (score 6):

I finally found a solution. It was a conjunction of several issues (gem versions, conflicting readline libraries).

Firstly, I refetched the readline lib

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

Then I uninstalled ruby

```
rvm remove 2.1.1
```

I installed ruby again

```
rvm install 2.1.1
```

I told RVM to use the default (2.1.1) Ruby

```
rvm use default
```

I reinstalled Rails and readline

```
gem install rails
gem install readline
```

I got an error again launching the console, but a slightly different one:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require':  /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: UP - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/readline.so (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/mammie/web/icosole/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
    from /opt/mammie/web/icosole/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/mammie/web/icosole/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:37:in `require'
    from /opt/mammie/web/icosole/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

So following this instructions (http://vkarthickeyan.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/mysql-symbol-lookup-error-usrlocalliblibreadline-so-6-undefined-symbol-up/), I got it to work:

```
cd /usr/local/lib
mkdir temp
mv libreadline* temp
ldconfig
apt-get update
```

Thanks to hunterboerner for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This worked out ok on a Solaris machine that had no readline, might work for you:

```
$ bundle exec irb
irb(main):001:0> require File.expand_path('config/boot')
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require File.expand_path('config/environment')
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /export/home/deploy/recon/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
Warning: NLS_LANG is not set. fallback to US7ASCII.
=> true
irb(main):027:0> require 'console_app'
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a while back, solved by typing: `rvm requirements` and installing what came back. Seemed to, although this was an older version of rvm so may no longer be relevant

Answer (score 0):

```
rvm reinstall 2.7.0
```

worked for me