# Rails console does not start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i try to run this command i get this

```
/home/miguel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
from /home/miguel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/miguel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
from /home/miguel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/miguel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `require'
from /home/miguel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `require_command!'
from /home/miguel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:59:in `console'
from /home/miguel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /home/miguel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0-p598, rails 4.1.0

I have this local gems installed

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340497/cannot-load-such-file-readline-loaderror-when-running-heroku-create-stack

Comment: kindly look at this result
Your query will solve
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340497/cannot-load-such-file-readline-loaderror-when-running-heroku-create-stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem here

http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/ruby/readline-in-ruby-with-rbenv/